# How to fill NULL value using min-max in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get front value and back value using min-max comparing.

Here is my sample table.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=322aafeb7970e25f9a85d0cd2f6c00d6

For example, this is `temp01` table.

I want to get start&end NULL value in temp01.

So, I fill

```
price = [NULL, NULL, 13000]
```

to

```
price = [12000, 12000, 13000]
```

Because the `12000` is minimum value in `[230, 1]`. And I fill end NULL is filled maximum value in `[cat01, cat02]` group

```
    | SEQ | cat01 | cat02 |   dt_day   | price |
    +-----+-------+-------+------------+-------+
    |  1  |  230  |   1   | 2019-01-01 |  NULL |
    |  2  |  230  |   1   | 2019-01-02 |  NULL |
    |  3  |  230  |   1   | 2019-01-03 | 13000 |
                       ...

    |  11 |  230  |   1   | 2019-01-11 |  NULL |
    |  12 |  230  |   1   | 2019-01-12 |  NULL |
    |  1  |  230  |   2   | 2019-01-01 |  NULL |
    |  2  |  230  |   2   | 2019-01-02 |  NULL |
    |  3  |  230  |   2   | 2019-01-03 | 12000 |

                       ...
    |  12 |  230  |   2   | 2019-01-11 |  NULL |
    |  13 |  230  |   2   | 2019-01-12 |  NULL |
```

[result]

```
    | SEQ | cat01 | cat02 |   dt_day   | price | 
    +-----+-------+-------+------------+-------+
    |  1  |  230  |   1   | 2019-01-01 | 12000 | --START
    |  2  |  230  |   1   | 2019-01-02 | 12000 | 
    |  3  |  230  |   1   | 2019-01-03 | 13000 |
    |  4  |  230  |   1   | 2019-01-04 | 12000 |
    |  5  |  230  |   1   | 2019-01-05 |  NULL |  
    |  6  |  230  |   1   | 2019-01-06 |  NULL |
    |  7  |  230  |   1   | 2019-01-07 | 19000 |
    |  8  |  230  |   1   | 2019-01-08 | 20000 |
    |  9  |  230  |   1   | 2019-01-09 | 21500 | 
    | 10  |  230  |   1   | 2019-01-10 | 21500 | 
    | 11  |  230  |   1   | 2019-01-11 | 21500 | 
    | 12  |  230  |   1   | 2019-01-12 | 21500 | 
    | 13  |  230  |   1   | 2019-01-13 | 21500 | --END   
    |  1  |  230  |   2   | 2019-01-01 | 12000 | --START
    |  2  |  230  |   2   | 2019-01-02 | 12000 | 
    |  3  |  230  |   2   | 2019-01-03 | 12000 | 
    |  4  |  230  |   2   | 2019-01-04 | 17000 |
    |  5  |  230  |   2   | 2019-01-05 | 22000 |   
    |  6  |  230  |   2   | 2019-01-06 |  NULL |
    |  7  |  230  |   2   | 2019-01-07 | 23000 |
    |  8  |  230  |   2   | 2019-01-08 | 23200 |
    |  9  |  230  |   2   | 2019-01-09 |  NULL |
    | 10  |  230  |   2   | 2019-01-10 | 24000 |
    | 11  |  230  |   2   | 2019-01-11 | 24000 | 
    | 12  |  230  |   2   | 2019-01-12 | 24000 | 
    | 13  |  230  |   2   | 2019-01-13 | 24000 | --END
```

Please, let me know what a good way to fill NULL using linear relationships.

Comment: So you want to update price that has a NULL with the min for the group if the row comes before the first non-value (using sequence), and you want to update NULL values after the last non-value with the max?  All other nulls you don't touch?

Comment: @AllanWind Yes, right! If I touch other nulls, I want to fill using interpolation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find the `min()` and `max()` for the price `GROUP BY` `cat01, cat02`.
Also find the `min` and `max` `seq` for the row where `price is not null`

after that it is just simply `inner join` to your table and update `where price is null`

```
with val as
(
    select cat01, cat02, 
           min_price = min(price), 
           max_price = max(price),
           min_seq   = min(case when price is not null then seq end),
           max_seq   = max(case when price is not null then seq end)
    from   temp01
    group by cat01, cat02
)
update t
set    price = case when t.seq < v.min_seq then min_price
                    when t.seq > v.max_seq then max_price
                    end
FROM   temp01 t
       inner join val v on   t.cat01 = v.cat01
                        and  t.cat02 = v.cat02
where  t.price is null
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d55eda521f04c76ce75d2c811f76e14c)

EDIT : returning the `price` as a new column in `SELECT` query

```
with val as
(
    select cat01, cat02, min_price = min(price), max_price = max(price),
           min_seq = min(case when price is not null then seq end),
           max_seq = max(case when price is not null then seq end)
    from   temp01
    group by cat01, cat02
)
select t.*,
       new_price = coalesce(t.price,
                            case when t.seq < v.min_seq then min_price
                                 when t.seq > v.max_seq then max_price
                                 end)
FROM   temp01 t
       left join val v on t.cat01 = v.cat01
                        and  t.cat02 = v.cat02
```

[Updated dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bd342a67141830b48bdd7ee932308ab3)

Comment: Thank you so much, Is it possible not using update clasue?